# How to most efficiently aggregate array of objects by ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

My starting data set is an array of objects containing metrics, each containing an ID.  I need to convert this data set into an array of aggregates, by ID.  For example:

```
const startingArray = [
  { id: 1, metricA: 5, metricB: 8, metricC: 1 }
  { id: 2, metricA: 4, metricB: 0, metricC: 7 }
  { id: 1, metricA: 9, metricB: 8, metricC: 2 }
  { id: 3, metricA: 1, metricB: 8, metricC: 2 }
  { id: 3, metricA: 6, metricB: 6, metricC: 1 }
  { id: 2, metricA: 3, metricB: 1, metricC: 9 }
  { id: 1, metricA: 3, metricB: 9, metricC: 8 }
]

const aggregates = {};

startingArray.forEach((item) => {
  if (!aggregates[item.id]) {
    aggregates[item.id] = {
      id: item.id,
      metricA: item.metricA, 
      metricB: item.metricB, 
      metricC: item.metricC
    }
  } else {
    aggregates[item.id].metricA += item.metricA,
    aggregates[item.id].metricB += item.metricB,
    aggregates[item.id].metricC += item.metricC
  }
});

// convert to flat array using lodash toArray() method
const endingArray = toArray(aggregates);

// results:
// [
//   { id: 1, metricA: 17, metricB: 25, metricC: 11 }
//   { id: 2, metricA: 5, metricB: 1, metricC: 16 }
//   { id: 3, metricA: 5, metricB: 8, metricC: 3 }
// ]
```

The arrays can be massive, what is the most efficient way of processing this data set?

Comment: in endingArray id:2  has misleading value for metricB it should be 1 or maybe startingArray has wrong value.......please check the value and share your code where you are having problem.

Comment: You're correct, I updated the question with correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could destructure `id` from the object and collect the rest for getting all entries and create a new object and sum all rest properties.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, metricA: 5, metricB: 8, metricC: 1 }, { id: 2, metricA: 4, metricB: 0, metricC: 7 }, { id: 1, metricA: 9, metricB: 8, metricC: 2 }, { id: 3, metricA: 1, metricB: 8, metricC: 2 }, { id: 3, metricA: 6, metricB: 6, metricC: 1 }, { id: 2, metricA: 3, metricB: 1, metricC: 9 }, { id: 1, metricA: 3, metricB: 9, metricC: 8 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { id, ...o }) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            r[id] ??= { id };
            r[id][k] = (r[id][k] || 0) + v;
        });
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```